# How to use composite item-key with Vuetify v-treeview

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Is it possible t give more than one field as key in the `item-key` prop in `v-treeview`?

I.e. my items look like this:

```
items = [
  {
    id:1
    type: "A"
  },
  {
    id:1
    type: "B"
  }
]
```

Id is unique within each type.

I tried to add a method and use that to provide the key, i.e

```
 methods: {
   getUniqueKey(item){
      console.log("called " + item);
      return item.id + "-" + item.type
   }
 }
```

and then use `v-treeview` like this:

```
<v-treeview
 v-model="tree"
 :open="open"
 :items="shared.displayList"
 item-key="getUniqueKey(item)"
 activatable
 open-on-click
>
```

However my method is never executed.

Comment: The [`item-key`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview) is type `string`, not a `function`. _"Property on supplied items used to keep track of node state. The value of this property has to be unique among all items."_

Comment: If you need a composite key, create one on the object.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thank you for your comment. I just assumed that there is a way without touching my model, since in `v-for` you can use methods.

Comment: Do you have un example for us ?
I need to use the key of array, not the id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
item-key="getUniqueKey(item)"
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.